# How to pass multiple lines to clipboard?

Tags: python, clipboard

Is there a way to send multiple lines of text to the clipboard?

I've used following commands but didn't work for me:

```
import os
text = """sample one \r\n sample two \r\n sample three"""
command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'.
os.system(command)
```

I want o/p as

```
sample one

sample two

sample three
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [clipboard module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clipboard/0.0.4):

```
import clipboard
clipboard.copy("line1\nline2")  # now the clipboard content will be string "line1\nline2"
clipboard.copy("line3") # add line3
text = clipboard.paste()  # text will have the content of clipboard
```

Right, so @Reman said the clipboard copy command overrides it, instead of appending. So, let's do the appending ourselves.

```
line = '\n'.join(line, new_line)
clipboard.copy(line)
text = clipboard.paste() # now all lines separated by newline will be on the clipboard.
```

Comment: Which, I believe, is a copy of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip/ but they are both basically the same. +1

Comment: the clipboard module doesn't append lines. Every copy command overwrites the current clipboard